# How to swapcase a string without using builtin functions

Tags: ruby

I am trying to swapcase a string without using builtin functions like `swapcase`.

I came up with with the following code:

```
a = gets.split
b = ""
for i in a
  if /[[:upper:]]/.match(i)
    b += i.downcase
  end
  if /[[:lower:]]/.match(i)
    b += i.upcase
  end
end
puts b
```

But it's producing a wrong output. How can I do it in Ruby?

Comment: By the way, your code uses no less than 7 different builtin methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to mimic swapcase with no argument.

```
p 'Hello'.chars.map { |c| c.upcase == c ? c.downcase : c.upcase }.join
 #=> "hELLO"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"Hello World!".tr("a-zA-Z", "A-Za-z")
# => "hELLO wORLD!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @sagarpandya82's answer but doesn't convert the string to an array and back.

```
"ComMMent maintEnaNt, vaChe tacHetée?".gsub(/./) do |c|
  c == c.upcase ? c.downcase : c.upcase
end
  #=> "cOMmmENT MAINTeNAnT, VAcHE TAChETÉE?"
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def fnswapcase(a):

    r = ' '

    for i in a:

        if ord(i) in range(97,123):
            r+=chr(ord(i)-32) 

        elif ord(i) in range(65,91):
            r+=chr(ord(i)+32)

        else:
            r+=i

        return r

a=input("Enter a string:")

print(fnswapcase(a))
```